# Ag-Grid not working in IE11 and angular 1.x

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in my angular project. Everything's okay at chrome untill i use IE for test this app. And wow, ag-grid can't load. Well, IE said:

```
 Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference
```

I think a problem's at ag-grid's lib is loaded before page's element done. Is that right?

Comment: Which IE version? Have you added polyfills for IE?